# C++ Reading from array of strings

Tags: c++

Question: 
How do I extract a character from a string that is an array?

Explained:
Normal strings

```
 string example=("Stack Over Flow");
 cout<<example[1];
```

The output will be:

```
 t
```

What I want is to extract a letter from an array of strings example:

```
string str[4];
str[0]="1st";
str[1]="2nd";
str[2]="3rd";
str[3]="4th";
cout<<str[2];
```

will print

```
3rd
```

how could i get the "t" from the `str[0]`?

Comment: `string example=("Stack Over Flow");` is not an array.

Comment: @soon OP never said it was.

Comment: You already know how to get a single characters from a `std::string` object, and e.g. `str[0]` *is* a `std::string` object.

Comment: @rozina, so, what does *"Explained: Normal array"* mean?

Comment: Sorry wrong choice of words,
what i mean to say is: the string consist of group of characters.
Misused the word array

Comment: The question is totally unclear. Can you please explain more of what you are asking for?

Comment: I am trying to extract the "t" from the str[0]=1st
but since this is an array, it cannot be extracted using one []

Answer (score 6, accepted):

just by doing as follow:

```
str[0][2]; // third character of first string
```

Some more examples:

```
string str[4];
str[0]="1st";
str[1]="2nd";
str[2]="3rd";
str[3]="4th";
cout<<str[0][2]<<endl; // t
cout<<str[2][1]<<endl; // r
cout<<str[3][2]<<endl; // h
```

Comment: Does that mean, i just need to add another []. when i use 2 dimensional array in strings? like: string str[4][4]; to access the characters I just need to: std::cout<<str[n][n][n]; (n) is a number

Comment: @PH.nischkar No. `[0]` is for the first string in the array. `[2]` is for the third character in that string. What do you think `[n]` on a `char` would do?

Comment: I am not sure what do you mean by "2 dimensional array in strings". If you have an array of `string` (`string myArray[5]`) you want to access the full string located at a specific index by doing `myArray[string_index]` , and then access the character of that particular `string`: `myArray[string_index][char_index]`

Comment: Meant to say 2 dimension strings.
so I need to use another []? will it be string[string_index][string_index][char_index]?

Comment: @PH.nischkar What's a two-dimensional string?

Comment: @PH.nischkar If you have a 2 dimensional array of strings then yes - `std::string array[4][4]`. Otherwise you have to explain what is a 2 dimensional string.

Comment: @PH.nischkar if you have an 2 dimensional array OF string (e.g. `string myArray[4][5]`). you need to access a character doing the following: `myArray[string_row_index][string_col_index][char_index]`

Answer (score 1):

```
std::string str[4];
str[0]="1st";
str[1]="2nd";
str[2]="3rd";
str[3]="4th";
```

Here `str` is an array of `std::string` objects. As you know you access elements of an array with `operator[]`. So the first string in the array is accessed with `str[0]`.

`std::string` offers `operator[]` as well. With it you can access characters of the string.

So lets take it step by step.

```
str - array
str[0] - std::string
str[0][0] - first character of the string str[0]
```

Answer (score 0):

You get 't' instead of 's' because you are printing it like this `cout<<example[1];`

you sohuld do it like this:

```
cout<<example[0][2];
```

Comment: Why `[1]`? OP wanted the `t`; the third character.

Comment: Read the question again.

Comment: You have to read the question more precisely. OP wants 't' from `str[0]`

Comment: My bad then, anyway, the way how you do it is the same, you just move one slot forward. Shouldn't be too hard to figure that one out...

Comment: @mheonyae That doesn't make your answer any better.

Answer (score 0):

YOu need one more `operator[]` call.  `str[2]` is using the `[]` of the array and returns a reference to the array element at index 2.  If you want to get the second character of the first array element then you need

```
str[0][2]
    ^  ^
string |
       character
```

Answer (score 0):

Class std::string has its own overloaded `operator []` that you used in the first your code snippet

```
 string example=("Stack Over Flow");
 cout<<example[1];
```

If you have an array of objects of type `std::string` then at first you need to access the desired object stored in the array using the built-in subscript `operator []` of arrays as for example

```
string str[4];
cout << str[1];
```

In this code snippet expression `str[1]` returns string stored in the second element (with index 1) of the array. Now you can apply the overloaded `operator []` of the class `std::string` as for example

```
string str[4];
cout << str[1][1];
```